# DRF, Channels and Model observers - message not being send over websocket to the client even when the model changes?

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I have these definitions in my DRF app:

Notification model:

```
from django.db import models


class Notifications(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(
        auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='notification_id')
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        "accounts.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, verbose_name="notification_receiver")
    date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="notification_datetime", blank=False)
    message = models.TextField(blank=False, verbose_name="notification_message")
```

NotificationSerializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from notifications.models import Notifications


class NotificationsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Notifications
        fields = ["date", "message"]
```

and a consumer:

```
from djangochannelsrestframework.generics import GenericAsyncAPIConsumer
from djangochannelsrestframework.observer import model_observer
from notifications.models import Notifications
from notifications.serializers import NotificationsSerializer


class NotificationsConsumer(GenericAsyncAPIConsumer):
    serializer_class = NotificationsSerializer
    queryset = Notifications.objects.all()

    async def connect(self, **kwargs):
        await self.model_activity.subscribe()
        await super().connect()

    @model_observer(Notifications)
    async def model_activity(self, message, observer=None, action=None, **kwargs):
        # send activity to frontend
        await self.send_json(message)

    @model_activity.serializer
    def model_serialize(self, instance, action, **kwargs):
        return NotificationsSerializer(instance=instance).data
```

I am following the documentation here: https://djangochannelsrestframework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/observer/observer.html

And I am connecting to this websocket via postman (if that makes a difference) - I am only developing an API and not a frontend.

Even if my Notifications table gets new data, no message is sent over the channel. What could be missing? Any insight would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Additional information: My database is postgres, I am using ` n = Notifications(...)` and `n = n.save()` to create an entry in the Notification table. The entry is definitely getting created.

If I create a simple consumer with the `receive` method, the server is able to send a message to the client - so it doesn't look like sending a message is the problem? If I have to guess, it is most likely because `model_observer` is not detecting that the table has been updated.